# How to configure HA/load-balancing at L3 for multiple NICs with quagga route injection and loopback addr (centos 7)

Tags: quagga

In a previous post this was mentioned by @Celada in the Enhanced version section: [Use NIC bonding with independent switches](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255923/use-nic-bonding-with-independent-switches)

My situation:
one centos 7.2 host with 4 100G NICs - all connected to ToR:

NIC1: 10.0.2.1/24

NIC2: 10.0.2.2/24

NIC3: 10.0.2.3/24

NIC4: 10.0.2.4/24

Requirement:
How to configure an extra loopback addr on the centos host and publish it as a single IP for HA/LB access for client machines within the rack, for iSCSI data-path access for storage.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the answer you cited:

> Configure with ip addr add 10.0.3.1/32 dev lo

So subnet 3 corresponds to the server resource.
Edit /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-* and `systemctl restart network`.
Quagga will pick this up and send link-state advertisements out your four NICs, or fewer during a NIC outage e.g. when you unplug one.

Clients, such as iSCSI initiators, will refer to HA address 10.0.3.1, transparently sending via one of the four NICs that is currently up.

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to have any good step-by-step quagga install & config doc for this topology or similar.

Comment: You might follow http://xmodulo.com/turn-centos-box-into-ospf-router-quagga.html or http://www.brianlinkletter.com/how-to-build-a-network-of-linux-routers-using-quagga/

Comment: Thanks @J_H. Configured quagga (zebra and ospfd) on a centos 7 cloud instance (VM). My configs in linked gdoc. Please comment if this is in the right direction and what else must happen to publish loopback HA address for clients to connect. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Hwlk3p1_NQBQYjT_g4BNbZY5iMsHNB39OzmGcV7_2KU/edit